# SetRootPath with QT, QFileSystemModel on Mac OS X

Tags: qt

I'm trying to create a file explorer in qt which is working but I cannot set the root path. I am running Mac OS X and no matter what root path I put in, the treeView always begins with

"/" the top folder.

I've spent 2 hours trying to figure this out.

```
if(QDir("SavedOutlines").exists()){
    fileModel = new QFileSystemModel;
    QDir dir;
    QString rootpath = dir.absolutePath() + "/SavedOutlines/";
    //QString path = "/Users/";
    fileModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);

    QModelIndex idx = fileModel->setRootPath(rootpath);
    ui->treeView->setCurrentIndex(idx);
    ui->treeView->setModel(fileModel);
    ui->treeView->show();
}
```

It seems like it's doing it at first and then resetting itself back to the top "/"

Answer (score 1):

`QFileSystemModel` always contains the whole filesystem, regardless of the `rootPath` that was chosen.

You can limit what is shown in the view itself with `QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex`:

```
QFileSystemModel *fileModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
ui->treeView->setModel(fileModel);
ui->treeView->setRootIndex(fileModel->setRootPath(rootpath));
```