# QFileSystemModel setRootPath

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I am attempting to create a Qt application which shows the contents of a folder (“Users” folder in Mac OS).
Here is the code:

```
QFileSystemModel *dirModel = new QFileSystemModel;
dirModel->setRootPath("/Users");

ui->listView->setModel(dirModel);
```

I also attempted using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877796/setrootpath-with-qt-qfilesystemmodel-on-mac-os-x)

When i run the application, instead of showing the content of the “/Users” Folder, it shows the root drive (note: not the content of the drive). The folder does exist and i also tried using other folders.

Comment: Did you attempt the code from the question you linked or from its answer ? (I just edited it to make it a little clearer).

Comment: I atteempted the code from the Question. I will attempt the answer now

Comment: `setRootPath` installs a file system watcher on a path to reflect changes. One needs `setRootIndex` as said in answers below. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setRootPath

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code has worked for me as well:

```
QFileSystemModel *dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
dirModel->setRootPath("/Users");

ui->listView->setModel(dirModel);
ui->listView->setRootIndex(dirModel->setRootPath("/Users"));
```

Comment: note, dirModel->setRootPath(...) returns a QModelIndex. You can call this once and pass the index into the setRootIndex

Answer (score 16):

Did you try forcing the index to show the directory ?

```
listView->setRootIndex(dirModel->index("/Users"));
```

This works fine for me:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QFileSystemModel model;
    model.setRootPath("/Users");
    QListView view;
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.setRootIndex(model.index("/Users/"));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I get an error :                                QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex failed : index must be from the currently set model